# insert/update referenced data from iothub in sql table by conditions with stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, cql, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I am workig on azure, there is a sql transact database with two tables and an iotHub which receives data from several devices. I have to check if the data are currently existing in the database and store them if not otherwise update the old data in the table.

tableOne like:

```
id   |   key1
-------------
1    |   abc
2    |   def
3    |   ghi
```

tableTwo like:

```
id    |   id_tableOne  |   key2         |   something
-------------------------------------------------------
77    |   2            |   Emil         |   welcome
78    |   1            |   Emil         |   here I am
79    |   1            |   Hans         |   hello world
```

stream as json msg coming from iotHub like this:

```
{
    "topic": "test",
    "key1": "ghi",
    "data": [{
        "key2": "Emil",
        "something": "lmn"
    },
    {
        "key2": "Hans",
        "something": "hij"
    },
    {
        "key2": "Gerda",
        "something": "xyz"
    }]
}
```

1. I want to get the id from tableOne by "key1" in the json stream
2. I want to check if the combination of id_tableOne (result from 1.) and key2 exists in
   tableTwo
3. if it does exist: update the row in tableTwo - else: insert new row in
   tableTwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [Stream data as input into Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs), only `eventhubs,iothubs and blob storage` are suppported in azure stream anslytics inputs.So, you can't filter the conditions with output sql database. As following sql is forbidden.

```
SELECT 
jaysqlserver2.id as id,
jaysqlserver2.id_tableOne as idTableOne,
jaysqlserver2.key2 as key2,
jaysqlserver2.somthing as something
from jsoninput
where jaysqlserver2.id_tableOne = jsoninput.key1
```

However,I provide you with an workaround.

Firstly, you could flat the `jsoninput` and save them into a temporary table in your target sql database.

```
SELECT 
    jsoninput.key1, 
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.key2,
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.something
INTO 
    output
FROM jsoninput
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(jsoninput.data) AS arrayElement
```

[image]

Then, you could follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) to use Azure Function Time Trigger to operate sql database automaticlly. Please refer to pseudo code as below:

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var text = "select temp.key1 as key1temp,temp.key2 as key2temp,
t1.id as id1,t1.key1 as key1,
t2.id as id2,t2.id_tableOne as tableOne,t2.key2 as key2,t2.something as something
from dbo.tabletemp as temp
left join dbo.table1 as t1 on temp.key1 = t1.key1
left join dbo.table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id_tableOne and temp.key2 = t2.key2
where t1.id is not null";

        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(text, conn);

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            string id2 = reader["id2"].ToString();
            if(id2 == null)
            {
                //execute insert sql
            }
            else
            {
                //execute update sql
            }
        }

        var delSql = "delete from dbo.temp";
        //execute delete data in temp table
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you for the answer. Yes your answer helped me! I was not able to implement it right now (time) but I have an idea how to do! Thanks a lot for this!  Btw: Is this way the "best-practise" --> I am not sure, but I think the requirement of storing data related to other stored data is not new, isnt't it?

Comment: @eid yes, I think this the best method I could thought so far,if you adopt this answer,please mark it.Thanks a lot.